# How to run a single module in a multimodule maven Project through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created integration tests as a maven multi module project. Each module represents an integration tests. When I do a build on jenkins it runs all the test , I couldnt find the option to run a single module ( in my case a test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very easy. In the Jenkins Configuration under **Build** check on the option to **Build modules in parallel** . This will help you to run individual module.
My Test project is a Maven project and it has a structure like :

- ## BusinessGroupModuleParentTests
- ### SomeBusinessLogicIntegrationTest
- ### SomeOtherBusinessLogicIntegrationTest

I can invoke each test individually now